# How do I work out how much ballast to buy for a foundation

Tags: concrete, foundation

I am about to commence a self build garage extension and am currently working out the quantities/quotes. My build has a concrete foundation underneath the perimeter wall (8m + 6m + 8m) and according to the plans they should be 0.6m wide and 0.2m deep.

By my rough calculations that's just over 2.5m^3 of concrete I have to mix up. Easy enough to do but I'm trying to work out how much ballast I need to buy to cover this. The bulk bags of ballast are around 800kg but that doesn't help me. Can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: By ballast you mean the stone and sand?  Concrete ratios are an easy google search, fast guess something 1 to 2 to 3.  Cement, stone, sand.  Don't go by this, just an example off my bean.  This sound big enough to have a cement mixer truck come by.  If this is for footings, then you want all the cement pour quite fast, taking a few days not good.

Comment: I'm not looking for concrete/sand mix ratios. I want to know how many of these bulk bags I will need to buy to fill the founds. I'd love to get a concrete company to come and do it but every one I've called has ignored me.

Comment: Ballast is an odd word over here.  I think now you mean the base(stone) to fill/compact before laying concrete footings on top, instead of mixing into cement to make concrete.  Words do change if they go over the pond.

Comment: Aright. I'm in the uk. Ballast is just a mix of sharp/builders sand and aggregate in a 2:1 ratio.

Comment: My local area calls it cement mix.  I think years ago it was three or four parts of ballast to one part cement.  So you need to know the pounds/kgs of cement needed for 2.5 cubic meters to find the amount of ballast needed.  There are cement calculators online that might help or give a headache.

Comment: @JamesDrinkwater are you talking stone base below the concrete, or stone *in* the concrete?